# How to repeat input until getting the right statement in java?

Tags: java

I'm new to java and right now I'm trying to write a coffee machine (kind of). What I'm trying to do is that I'm have been trying to use a while loop to loop the input again until the user puts the input that I have been stating it. but nothing seem to happen can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] coffeeName = {"Espesso", "Carpucino", "Moca", "Latte","Amricano"};
        String[] topping = {"Whip-cream", "Ice-cream","Oreo","No topping"};
        
        Scanner np = new Scanner(System.in); 
        coffee cf = new coffee();
        // Asking for the coffee.
        
        for (int  i = 0; i < coffeeName.length; i++) { 
                  System.out.println(coffeeName[i]);
        }
        
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(coffeeName);
        
        System.out.println("What coffee do you want today: "); 
        
        String chooseCoffee = np.nextLine();
        chooseCoffee = chooseCoffee.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + chooseCoffee.substring(1);
        
        if (!list.contains(chooseCoffee)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry the product are not in the list...please try again"); 
        }
        
        //
        
        boolean tempHotCold = true;
        String coffeTemp;

        System.out.println("You want it cold or hot?: ");
        coffeTemp = np.nextLine();
        coffeTemp = coffeTemp.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + coffeTemp.substring(1);

        do {
                if (coffeTemp.equalsIgnoreCase("cold")) {
                    coffeTemp = cf.coldCoffee();
                    tempHotCold = true;
                }
                if (coffeTemp.equalsIgnoreCase("hot")) {
                    coffeTemp = cf.hotCoffee();
                    tempHotCold = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please choose hot or cold...");
                    tempHotCold = false;
                    return;
                } 
        }while (!tempHotCold);          
        System.out.println(chooseCoffee+" " + coffeTemp + ", coming right up!:)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your not asking for another line of input as part of your loop, its just going to keep looping using the table value of coffeTemp

Comment: coffeTemp = np.nextLine();   this line should be inside the do{ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a List Interface to determine if the entered coffee exists. You already have all that within your `coffeeNames[]` array. It's understandable as to why you want to utilize such a mechanism since expecting a User to enter pretty much anything longer than a single character is relatively error prone.

You may want to rethink how you want the User to select this/her desired coffee and remove the risk for an invalid entry altogether. Consider a menu scheme, for example:

```
Available Coffee's. Which would you like?
  1) Espesso
  2) Carpucino
  3) Moca
  4) Latte
  5) Amricano
  6) Quit
Which coffee would you like today: -->
```

In the above situation, the User can select the desired coffee by merely entering a single digit. The name of the coffee doesn't need to be typed out which (as you know) just opens more room for entry errors. The menu item number supplied by the User represents the index number of the coffee contained within the `coffeeNames[]` array (*supplied menu item number* - 1). Of course you still want to carry out entry validation with regards to the fact that the number supplied is within the menu range (1 to 6) and the fact that it is indeed a numerical digit that was supplied and not some alpha character. This can be easily accomplished by utilizing the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method and with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex). An entry deemed invalid would permit the User to make a correct entry. Below is how this might look:

```
Scanner np = new Scanner(System.in); 
String[] coffeeNames = {"Espesso", "Cappuccino", "Moca", "Latte", "Amricano"};
String[] topping = {"Whip-cream", "Ice-cream", "Oreo", "No topping"};
    
Coffee cf = new Coffee();

// Asking for the desired coffee.
String desiredCoffee = "";
String coffeeChoice = "";
int maxMenuOptions = coffeeNames.length + 1; // Plus 1 because Quit is added to the menu.
while(coffeeChoice.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Available Coffee's. Which would you like?");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < coffeeNames.length; i++) { 
        System.out.println("  " + (i + 1) + ") " + coffeeNames[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("  " + (i + 1) + ") Quit");
    System.out.print("Which coffee would you like today: --> "); 
    coffeeChoice = np.nextLine();
    // Validate that only digits 1 to 6 (in this case) are entered.
    if (!coffeeChoice.matches("[1-" + maxMenuOptions + "]")) {
        System.err.println("Invalid menu choice (" + coffeeChoice + ")! Try again...");
        System.out.println();
        coffeeChoice = "";
    }
}
if (coffeeChoice.equals(String.valueOf(maxMenuOptions))) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Quiting - Bye Bye.");
    System.exit(0);
}
desiredCoffee = coffeeNames[Integer.valueOf(coffeeChoice) - 1];
System.out.println("You chose the coffee: --> " + desiredCoffee);
```

Do something similar with your other prompts as well. The less typing the User needs to do, the less typo errors will occur.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, it really helps me a lot in this java journey. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, You will want to do something like

```java
String chooseCoffee = np.nextLine();
while (!list.contains(chooseCoffee)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry the product are not in the list...please try again"); 
            choosecoffee = np.nextLine()
        }
```